# My device read Electroconductivity values like 478.1 but highchart always display it rounded. i got 478. how can i format my axis?

Tags: highcharts

```
yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: 'Visits'
    },
     labels: {
        format: '{value:.2f}'
     },
    plotLines: [{
        value: 0,
        width: 1,
        color: '#808080'
    }]
}
```

Comment: can you add and live demo like jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Use Highcharts.numberFormat() . For example :

```
$("#container").highcharts({
    // ...
   yAxis: {
            labels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 2); 
                        //First parameter is the raw number to format and second parameter is the desired number of decimals.       
                    }
              }
         }
});
```

Hope this helps you. Please check out this sample fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/wGLgE/2/

Comment: Nothing change in my charts

Comment: @JuniCorderoMagtibayArcal : can u please make a fiddle of ur work? so i could find out the issue. Check out this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/wGLgE/2/ here you can see the decimal points in y axis.